# HTML generic control that works independent of backend server code language

Tags: html, controls, custom-controls

How can we create an html control that works regardless of what language the backend server code is in?

I need to create a HTML generic control that works regarding of whether the server is in PHP, C# or Ruby.

Answers will be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML controls, or forms all work independently from your backend language. You use a form with POST or GET to send the data to your backend script. Your HTML code doesn't change whether the backend script is in PHP, ASP, JSP, Perl, ...

Comment: The server-side code used may pose restrictions on field names that you can use.